# Retrieving result of user selections as input to call to external program in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want a user to select an input file (eg. ~/MySampleTextFile.txt) and then select an output directory. I want the program to then copy the input file to the output directory. I was wondering how I can access the input file and output directory as input to the on_runButton_clicked() function below? Thanks for your help.

[UI of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KYud.png)

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>

extern std::string selected_output_dir;
using namespace std;
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    QString on_inputFileNameButton_clicked();

    void on_runButton_clicked();

    QString on_outputDirButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
# include <QFileDialog>
# include <QMessageBox>
# include <QString>
# include <QProcess>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString MainWindow::on_inputFileNameButton_clicked()
{
    QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
                this,
                tr("Select file to analyze"),
                "~",
                "All files (*.*);; Text file (*.txt)"
                );
//    Qstring selected_output_dir = filename;
    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("File Name"),filename);
    return filename;
}

void MainWindow::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    QString input_file_name = "/Users/Shared/MySampleTextFile.txt";
    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("File Name"),input_file_name);
    QString output_dir = "/home/";
    QString command_to_call = "cp " + input_file_name +" " + output_dir; // copy the input_file_name to output_dir
    QProcess::execute (command_to_call);
}

QString MainWindow::on_outputDirButton_clicked()
{
    QString output_dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                                "",
                                                QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Output directory"),output_dir);
    return output_dir;
}
```

mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>someProgramv0.1</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="runButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>150</x>
      <y>160</y>
      <width>115</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Run</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="mainProgramTitle">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>130</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; color:#ff0000;&quot;&gt;SomeProgram v0.1&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>269</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="inputFileNameButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Input File</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="outputDirButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Output Folder</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu_File">
    <property name="title">
     <string>&amp;File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menu_File"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: I understand you right? You want to use filename (name of file) from on_inputFileNameButton_clicked() function and output_dir (name of dir) from on_outputDirButton_clicked() function in on_runButton_clicked() function?

Comment: That's correct, and I want to be able to store these strings somehow and feed them to the on_runBotton_clicked() function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `filename` and `output_dir` like this (in private section of MainWindow):

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

...

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString filename_;
    Qstring output_dir_;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And use it like this in `on_runButton_clicked()`:

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

...

QString MainWindow::on_inputFileNameButton_clicked()
{
    filename_ =QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
                this,
                tr("Select file to analyze"),
                "~",
                "All files (*.*);; Text file (*.txt)"
                );
//    Qstring selected_output_dir = filename;
    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("File Name"),filename_);
    return filename;
}

void MainWindow::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    QString command_to_call = "cp " + filename_ +" " + output_dir_; // copy the input_file_name to output_dir
    QProcess::execute (command_to_call);
}

QString MainWindow::on_outputDirButton_clicked()
{
    output_dir_ = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                                "",
                                                QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Output directory"),output_dir);
    return output_dir;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kirill this is great

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after. It copies the file to the new directory with the same name and removes the old one

Use `QFile`

```
QString inputFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select File"), QDir::currentPath(), "All files" (*.*));
QString outputDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Select Directory"), QDir::currentPath());

QFile file(inputFile)
QFileInfo fileInfo(file);

file.copy(outputDir + "/" + fileInfo.fileName());
file.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks Dillydill! I am less interested in the copying aspect of the function (I want to call a different external program), but am mostly interested in how I can access variables produced by functions outside of those functions. I apologize, I see that wasn't entirely clear from my problem statement, just meant to include a reproducible example.

Comment: No problem. It looks like Kirill's answer should accomplish that. Although Kirill's answer will work perfectly fine, I would prefer to make a separate class to store all the information that you need. That way you can create the class in separate files and make your code neater. This way your mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp will mostly contain code regarding the ui. Then all of you have to do is create an instance of that class in mainwindow and pass it through to your functions (or as a private variable). Hope that makes sense